# Passing a variable value through a html button

Tags: php, html, yii

I'm using HTML within a PHP script. I've set the 'client_id' as '1' but 'client_id' is a variable itself which is being used in a controller to retrieve the client id ($client_id).  I don't want to pass through a default value but rather pass through the variable so it can retrieve the value $client_id holds.  If I set 'client_id => 'null' then I just get an error saying the client can't be found (which is correct, as there is no client being passed through). If I set 'client_id' => '1', it works but I don't want to pass through a static value.

This is the code for the button:

```
<?= Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-export"></span> Download full questions template', ['export/export-template', 'client_id' => '1', 'type' => 'full'], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary pull-right']); ?>
```

This is the code to retrieve the $client_id:

````
```public function actionExportTemplate( $client_id= null, $type = null)
{
    // Get client
    $Client = self::getClient($client_id);```
````

```
private function getClient($client_id)
    {
        if (isset(Yii::$app->user->identity->client_id)) {
            $client_id = Yii::$app->user->identity->client_id;
        }
        
        $Client = Client::findOne($client_id);
        
        if (is_null($Client)) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('Client not found');
        }

        return $Client;
    }
```

so my question is, how would I pass through '$client_id'  in the HTML button?

Comment: _“This is the code to retrieve the $client_id”_ - that actually rather looks like it fetches a whole client object, not just an ID. So you will likely have to get the ID from that object first of all. And then you simply put it where you currently have the static `'1'` in your code … replace that with either a variable that holds your client ID, or the appropriate method call on the appropriate object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you have not mentioned the controller code , but you can pass variable form controller to view like that
suppose this is controller class code

```
function actionExportTemplate( $client_id= null, $type = null){
  $clientId = getClient($client_id);
  return $this->render('demo', ['clientId' => $clientId]);
}

private function getClient($client_id)
{
    if (isset(Yii::$app->user->identity->client_id)) {
        $client_id = Yii::$app->user->identity->client_id;
    }
    
    $Client = Client::findOne($client_id);
    
    if (is_null($Client)) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('Client not found');
    }

    return $Client;
}
```

now suppose this is your **view code** I name it `demo.php` on my side.

```
<?= Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-export"></span> Download full questions template', ['export/export-template', 'client_id' => $clientId, 'type' => 'full'], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary pull-right']); ?>
```